# cocos2d-x determine where a object will be based off its vector

Tags: c++, math, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, trigonometry

In my game i want my towers to shoot where the enemy is going to be by the time the bullet reaches it.

i don't want my bullet to curve, i want it to shoot directly to the estimated location based on the speed the unit is moving and the direction it is moving

My thought is that i determine the direction of my enemy by subtracting its current position from its last position every time it moves. so lets say that its direction is (1,1)

after that i am not 100% sure what logic i would need to do.

i am thinking i need to know the distance from the tower to the enemy to determine the time i need to estimate how far the enemy is going to be when the bullet should reach it.

i really don't know where to start with this one, so if anyone can give me some pointers on how i should handle this solution.

Comment: You know the direction of your enemy ((1,1) in your example), so you need also the speed of your enemy, to estimate where it will be when your bullet reaches it. Of course I assume know when you will fire your bullet, and the speed of your bullet.

Answer (score 0):

In case of uniformly accelerated linear movement

```
x(t) = x0 + vx * t
y(t) = y0 + vy * t
```

where `vx`, `vy` are projections of velocity `v` on coordinate axis. Velocity is vector which scalar value is speed, and direction in the direction of movement. In your case, if your direction vector is normalized, multiply it by speed to get velocity.

You know starting position: `(x0, y0)`. You only need projections `vx` and `vy`. If `w` is angle between x-axis and velocity, then

```
vx = v * cos(w)
vy = v * sin(w)
```

As for angle: use `atan2f` function, or cocos2d function `ccpToAngle` (which uses `atan2f` itself) with normalized direction vector.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose , the position vector of your enemy is `P`, his velocity is `E` and the speed of your bullet is `b`. [ I will use upper case letter for vector, and its corresponding lower case for its modulus]

Suppose, after time `t` the enemy will be hit.

Then, `t*B = P + t*E` [where `B` is the velocity of the bullet. Note, you don't know the direction of `B`, but you the mod value of it, `b`]

Now try to calculate `t` ! It is not easy I think, there is another unknown, the directional vector of `B`. You have to replace it with known variables and `t` and then solve if for `t`. Use other vector tools, like dot product to get the angle between `P` and `B`, to get to other equations and relation between other vectors.

Update:
I just did some short calculation, I might be wrong. Just let me know if this works.
`t` is the real positive solution of the following equation:
`t^2*(e^2-b^2) + t*(2*p*e*cos(the angle between P and E)) + p^2 = 0`